# How to increase the rectangle size dynamically?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have written a c# code which will generate a pdf and it will contain a rectangle and inside that rectangle i have table which grows dynamically from database.

What is happening now is when i increase the size of table by adding more and more rows statically (which will be dynamic after DB connections). The data below the table goes down because of increase in height of table because of row adding 
and some text written below goes down and disappears.

What i want ?
I want to grow the size of rectangle such that it must send the data to next page and (rather than disappearing it).

My code for RECTANGLE is:

```
/*Creating border using rectangle*/
PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(doc.PageSize);
rectangle.Left += document.LeftMargin - 10;
rectangle.Right -= document.RightMargin;
rectangle.Top -= document.TopMargin ;
rectangle.Bottom += document.BottomMargin;
content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
content.Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
content.Stroke();
  ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(content);
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(rectangle);
```

And code for table is :

```
PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(8);
table2.WidthPercentage = 80;
float[] colWidths = { 110, 80, 80, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70 }; /*Set different column widths*/
table2.SetWidths(colWidths);
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("d");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("d");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("");
table2.AddCell("d");
...................
...................
ct.AddElement(table2);
ct.Go();
```

It contains a paragraph which disappears on increasing the table rows. It should go to next page rather.

Comment: You chose to use iTextSharp routines that directly draw on the canvas of the current page. As soon as you start using these routines, you are responsible for distributing your content over multiple pages. If you want iText to automatically distribute your content over multiple pages for you, add the content (e.g. your table) to the `Document` instance instead.

Comment: That been said, please read the docs: *A call to the method go will return one of the following situations: the column ended or the text ended. If the column ended, a new column definition can be loaded with the method setColumns and the method go can be called again.*